# How to test if HDF5 Compound Type already exists in file?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have several datasets that have different compound types. 
I want to reuse these compound types.

How can I test whether a compound type already exists or not?
I tried the `attrExists` function, but it always return 0 eventhough my compound datatype is `committed`.

```
H5::DataSet* dataset;
H5::CompType mtype1;
mtype1 = ( sizeof(s1_t) );
mtype1.insertMember( MEMBER1, HOFFSET(s1_t, a), H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT);
mtype1.insertMember( MEMBER3, HOFFSET(s1_t, c), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
mtype1.insertMember( MEMBER2, HOFFSET(s1_t, b), H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT);
dataset = new H5::DataSet(this->file->createDataSet(ss.str(), mtype1, space));

H5Tcommit1(this->file->getLocId(), "s1_t", mtype1.getId());

std::cout << "mtype1.committed(): " << mtype1.committed() << std::endl;
std::cout << "this->file->attrExists(\"s1_t\"): " << this->file->attrExists("s1_t") << std::endl;
```

The output is

```
mtype1.committed(): 1
this->file->attrExists("s1_t"): 0
```

... which shows, that the data type is committed but can not be found by the `attrExists` function.

Is there a different way to check whether the compound datatype exists in the file?